# How to get my data created in VF page to show up in a related list

Tags: visualforce

I'm new to Salesforce VF development.

so Here is the situation. I have created a custom object call "calculator", and is it under the Opportunities object and added a related list in the Opportunitie page. I have overridden the New button on the related list to my visualforce page. Now I am wondering how to I get the data stored in Calculator object to show up under (as a list) the caculator related list within the Opportunities page.

So. If I created a new calculator under a certain Opportunity, it would show up in the related list under that certain Opportunity detail page. Hope I explained things clear enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

On the Opportunity page, click on "Edit Layout" (top right corner).

Once in edit mode, go to your calculator related list and click on the wrench icon.
If that list does not exist on your layout, add it with the "edit layout menu" at the top of the page. On the left hand side, you will see "Related List", click on it and drag/drop your calculator list.

A window will be open under which you can select the field you would like to display.

Hope I understood your question correctly.

Comment: Yes, I have that part done. But When I saved data entered on my VF page, it is in the database, but not showing up in the related list. (the related list is always empty)

Comment: View one of your calculator record, can you confirm that the opportunity field is correctly set ? If so, try refreshing the page and see if the related list is populated correctly.

Comment: Can you explain "opportunity field is correctly set". Thanks so much

Comment: If it's set correctly then the field value will be a link pointing to the Opportunity that you created it from using your "custom New button".

Comment: The Opportunity field is a lookup filed to the Opportunity Object under my Calculator Object.

Comment: Make sure your Calculator object has only one lookup(Opportunity) field. If you have more than one, check the relationship name on the field to confirm that you have picked the right related list on the Opportunity pagelayout. Can you confirm that the Opportunity lookup field is correctly set on your calculator object? Not defined, but set. If all the above is working for you, can you test the following:  create a calculator object using your custom new button on the related list. Refresh the Opportunity page and check if any data is showing up under the related list.